# How to avoid dependency conflics when installing vim from source?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, installing, linux-ubuntu

I run Ubuntu 14.04 and want to use YouCompleteMe with vim for python and c++ code completion. YouCompleteMe requires vim 7.4.143+, which is higher than what I get with apt-get, so I follow [this](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) tutorial to install newer vim from source. Before installation I do run `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove vim vim-runtime gvim` to get rid of everything that could depend on the previous vim version, and I also use *checkinstall* instead of plain *make install*. After this I run `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure that new vim did not introduce any disturbances, and I still have the latest version of everything running. After that, I can use vim YouCompleteMe working smoothly.

What does not work smoothly though is Ubuntu's auto-update: the next time that I accept graphical offer from the operating system to upgrade my packages, the update process crashes going into some troubles, and I cannot run vim on from that point. `sudo apt-get -f install` proposes me to install *vim-common* and *vim-runtime*, and when I do that I have the old version of vim once again without being able to use YouCompleteMe.

How can I find which packages my new vim has conflict with? How could I resolve that conflict?

Comment: you can leave the package version on disk. They won't conflict with your self compiled Vim. And if you use --with-prefix=/home/local/ you don't need to change anything in the system path.

Comment: You might have disabled the repository and somehow Ubuntu failed to resolve dependencies. I recommend asking this question on [ubuntu.se] instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using exactly *make install* instead of *checkinstall*, unlike it is advised in [the tutorial](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source). Though it is said there that *checkinstall* is preferable as it allows for easier further deinstallation of the package, as for now I have not noticed any problems with package management - all updates run smoothly, and vim does not cause any troubles as well.